# How should I go about learning PHP given a background in C#.NET?

Tags: learning, c#, php

I have developed a few websites and applications using C#, and lately I've been developing a website in ASP.NET MVC. To be honest, this has pissed me off somewhat as it has me feeling like I have zero knowledge. So many things work under the hood in .NET that I'm just not able to focus and understand what is left to the developer and how these things are done.

Now, the question that prompted me to make this post is: **How should I proceed for learning PHP from a very basic standpoint?** Mind you, I have no idea about this language at all, just seen some code and heard people talking.

Comment: I have removed the refrence to python as language comparisons are off topic here. If you want more info on how to learn python please search the site or raise a new question

Comment: Please don't learn PHP. Learn LISP, Forth, or Scala, or Clojure, or Python. If you want to understand things "under the hood," learn a better language. PHP probably won't deepen or broaden your understanding of programming.

Comment: Since you've already learned a language descended from C (i.e. C#), I would recommend either LISP or Forth. They are very different models of computation from C-based languages and will help you grow intellectually to be a better programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by learning basics of PHP. There are a [lot of books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90924/what-is-the-best-php-programming-book) for PHP and it's syntax is not so complicated so you will probably pick up basic stuff pretty quickly. You can then start learning about some framework e.g. [Symfony](http://symfony.com/get_started) or [Zend](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html) framework.

I would suggest you to find a good IDE to work in because it's pretty frustrating when you need to do everything manually (Zend Studio is great IDE if you're using Zend framework).